# Cuda illegal memory access error when using array indexes stored in another array

Tags: cuda, fortran

I'm using cuda fortran and I've been struggling with this problem in one simple kernel and I couldn't find the solution.
Isn't it possible to use integer values stored in an array as the indexes for another array?

Here's a simple example (edited to include also the main program):

```
program test
  use cudafor

  integer:: ncell, i
  integer, allocatable:: values(:)
  integer, allocatable, device :: values_d(:)


  ncell = 10

  allocate(values(ncell), values_d(ncell))

  do i=1,ncell
        values(i) = i
  enddo


  values_d = values


  call multipleindices_kernel<<< ncell/1024+1,1024 >>> (values_d,
 + ncell)

  values = values_d

  write (*,*) values


  end program test

!////////////////////////////////////////////////////

attributes(global) subroutine multipleindices_kernel(valu, ncell)
use cudafor
  implicit none
  integer, value:: ncell   ! ncell = 10
  integer :: valu(ncell)
  integer :: tempind(10)
  integer:: i

  tempind(1)=10
  tempind(2)=3
  tempind(3)=5
  tempind(4)=7
  tempind(5)=9
  tempind(6)=2
  tempind(7)=4
  tempind(8)=6
  tempind(9)=8
  tempind(10)=1

  i = (blockidx%x - 1 ) * blockdim%x + threadidx%x

  if (i .LE. ncell) then
        valu(tempind(i))= 1
  endif


  end subroutine
```

I understand that if there were repeated values in the tempind array different threads could be accessing the same memory location for reading or writting, but that is not the case.
Even though, this gives the error "0: copyout Memcpy (host=0x303610, dev=0x3e20000, size=40) FAILED: 77(an illegal memory access was encountered).

Does anyone know if it is possible to use this indexes coming from another array in cuda?

After some additional tests, I've noticed that the problem occurs not while running the kernel itself, but on the transfer of the data back to CPU (if I remove "values = values_d" then no error is displayed). Also, if I substitute in the kernel valu(tempind(i)) by valu(i) it works fine, but I want to have the indexes coming from an array since the purpose of this test is to make a parallelization of a CFD code where the indexes are stored like that.

Comment: It is possible, so the error is probably something to do with valu. It's been a while since I did any CUDA Fortran, but shouldn't it have the device attribute? In any case, I suggest you post a complete reproducing example, otherwise it's going to be pretty hard for anybody to help you.

Comment: variable declarations within the kernel subroutine defintion (even for parameters) do not require the `device` attribute.  That is required in the main program code, however(for variables to be used by kernel subroutines).  This looks odd:  `integer :: valu(ncell)` I would have expected: `integer :: valu(:)` but it may be OK.  I agree a complete reproducing example is needed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answers. I've edited to post also the simple program test that calls the kernel and added additional comments to help us get to the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the generated executable doesn't pass the variable `ncell` to the kernel correctly. Running the application through `cuda-memcheck` shows that threads outside of the 1-10 are passing through the branch statement, and adding a print statement to print `ncell` inside the kernel also gives strange answers.

It used to be a requirement that all `attributes(global)` subroutines had to reside within a module. This requirement seems to have been relaxed in more recent versions of CUDA Fortran (I cannot find references to it in the programming guide). I believe the code outside of the module is causing the error here. By placing `multipleindices_kernel` within a module and using that module in `test` I consistantly get correct answers with no errors. The code for this is below:

```
module testmod
contains
attributes(global) subroutine multipleindices_kernel(valu, ncell)
  use cudafor
  implicit none
  integer, value:: ncell   ! ncell = 10
  integer :: valu(ncell)
  integer :: tempind(10)
  integer:: i

  tempind(1)=10
  tempind(2)=3
  tempind(3)=5
  tempind(4)=7
  tempind(5)=9
  tempind(6)=2
  tempind(7)=4
  tempind(8)=6
  tempind(9)=8
  tempind(10)=1

  i = (blockidx%x - 1 ) * blockdim%x + threadidx%x

  if (i .LE. ncell) then
        valu(tempind(i))= 1
  endif


  end subroutine
end module testmod

  program test
  use cudafor
  use testmod

  integer:: ncell, i
  integer, allocatable:: values(:)
  integer, allocatable, device :: values_d(:)


  ncell = 10

  allocate(values(ncell), values_d(ncell))

  do i=1,ncell
        values(i) = i
  enddo


  values_d = values


  call multipleindices_kernel<<< ncell/1024+1,1024 >>> (values_d, ncell)

  values = values_d

  write (*,*) values


  end program test

!////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Hi Jez, thank you for the answer. Indeed it solved the problem. I don't know if it works in your compiler like that, but in my case, with PGI compiler, I had to place the "contains" statement in the beginning of the module. Not sure though why this didn't work without being in a module, since I've  been using other kernels like that without problem until now (not using indexes stored in other array).

Comment: You're correct. `contains` somehow got lost when I pasted! Fixed.